# Compiler error when using pattern matching on list of pairs in scala

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, pattern-matching

I'm learning Scala pattern matching and encountered the following issue:

Suppose i have the list of integers and using pattern matching to match the last element:

```
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil

list match { 
   case xs :+ 3 => println("Matched")
   case _ => println("Not matched")
}
```

In this case it works without problems and "Matched" is printed.

But the issue comes when i use list of pairs instead:

```
val list = ('a', 1) :: ('b', 2) :: ('c', 3) :: Nil
list match {
   case xs :+ ('c', 3) => println("Matched")
   case _ => println("Not mathed")
}
```

When i write this, i get the following error:

```
<console>:14: error: too many patterns for object :+ offering
(List[(Char, Int)], (Char, Int)): expected 2, found 3
          case xs :+ ('c', 3) => println("Matched")
                  ^
 <console>:14: error: type mismatch; 
 found   : Char('c')
 required: (Char, Int)
          case xs :+ ('c', 3) => println("Matched")
```

Did i miss something here and if there is some correct way to do this?

scala version is 2.11.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the appended pair with parenthesis. The method :+ accepts one parameter. If you dont have extra parenthesis, two parameters are being assumed.

```
list match {
     case xs :+ (('c', 3)) => println("Matched")
     case _ => println("Not mathed")
  }
```